Signal R authentication is showing Context details to be null
I am trying to get my logged in user and connection id to map user accordingly.
Below is my program.cs file:

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
builder.Services.TryAddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    options.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn = true;
}).AddIdentityCookies();

//Database Connection
DatabaseConnection connectionString = new(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("OffDatabase") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found."));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(DatabaseConnection.ConnectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
  .AddSignInManager()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
  .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();

builder.Services.AddCors();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseMiddleware<BlazorCookieLoginMiddleware>();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(AuthenticationLibrary._Imports).Assembly)
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapHub<ItemAccessHub>("/itemaccesshub");

app.Run();


Below is my ItemAccessHub:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Admin.Hubs
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ItemAccessHub : Hub
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, (string UserEmail, string Module, string UserName)> RowLocks = new();
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> UserConnections = new();

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var userEmail = Context.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
            var userName = Context.User?.Identity?.Name; // Assuming the username is stored in the Name claim

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmail))
            {
                UserConnections[userEmail] = Context.ConnectionId;
            }

            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            var userEmail = Context.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmail) && UserConnections.ContainsKey(userEmail))
            {
                // Remove the user's connection ID
                UserConnections.TryRemove(userEmail, out _);
                var lockedRows = RowLocks.Where(x => x.Value.UserEmail == userEmail).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
                foreach (var rowId in lockedRows)
                {
                    RowLocks.TryRemove(rowId, out _);
                    Clients.Others.SendAsync("RowUnlocked", rowId);
                }
            }

            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }

        public Task LockRow(string rowId, string module)
        {
            var userEmail = Context.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
            var userName = Context.User?.Identity?.Name;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmail) && !RowLocks.ContainsKey(rowId))
            {
                RowLocks[rowId] = (userEmail, module, userName);
                return Clients.Others.SendAsync("RowLocked", rowId, userName);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task UnlockRow(string rowId)
        {
            var userEmail = Context.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmail) && RowLocks.ContainsKey(rowId))
            {
                if (RowLocks.TryGetValue(rowId, out var lockInfo) && lockInfo.UserEmail == userEmail)
                {
                    RowLocks.TryRemove(rowId, out _);
                    return Clients.Others.SendAsync("RowUnlocked", rowId);
                }
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}


Below is my Middleware code:
public class BlazorCookieLoginMiddleware
{
    public static IDictionary<Guid, LoginInfo> Logins { get; private set; }
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, LoginInfo>();


    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public BlazorCookieLoginMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInMgr)
    {
        // Skip Blazor-related paths
        if (context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/_blazor") || context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/_framework"))
        {
            await _next(context);
            return;
        }

        if (context.Request.Path == "/login" && context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("key"))
        {
            var key = Guid.Parse(context.Request.Query["key"]);
            var info = Logins[key];

            var result = await signInMgr.PasswordSignInAsync(info.Email, info.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            info.Password = null;
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                Logins.Remove(key);
                context.Response.Redirect("/");
                return;
            }
            else if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                //TODO: redirect to 2FA razor component
                context.Response.Redirect("/loginwith2fa/" + key);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //TODO: Proper error handling
                context.Response.Redirect("/loginfailed");
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (context.Request.Path == "/logout" && context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("key"))
        {
            var key = Guid.Parse(context.Request.Query["key"]);
            await signInMgr.SignOutAsync();
            Logins.Remove(key);
            context.Response.Redirect("/");
            return;

        }
        else
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
            return;
        }
    }
}

This is how create connection and call:
    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
   .WithUrl(UriHelper.ToAbsoluteUri("/itemaccesshub"))
    .Build();

hubConnection.On<string, string>("RowLocked", (rowId, username) =>
{
    rowLocks[rowId] = username;
    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
});

hubConnection.On<string>("RowUnlocked", rowId =>
{
    rowLocks.Remove(rowId);
    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
});

await hubConnection.StartAsync();


However, my context is always null:


I have gone through all documentation on Microsoft but not able to make it work. I need context information (Authorized user) details for keeping track and manage connection id.


I have gone through all documentation on Microsoft but not able to make it work. I need context information (Authorized user) details for keeping track and manage connection id.

Read the documentation link at the bottom re Auth. You have to setup middleware as Signalr can use many protocols and therefore the Auth has to be forwarded through middleware. Im not sure this is still the case in .net8 though. 2nd you have to put [Authorize] on the hub class AND METHODS for the context to evaluate the id I believe.

Do you have implementation for the middleware or how it should look like ?
